# How large are the steps on onAdjustVolume of the VolumeProvider?

Tags: android

I'm implementing a `VolumeProvider` but I don't know what volume I should set my player to once `onAdjustVolume` is called. All it gives me is the direction. Right now I'm using `getCurrentVolume() + direction` but that only works if the steps are equal to `AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER` or  `AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE` or `AudioManager.ADJUST_SAME`.

So how can I know what the steps will be?

Thanks.

Edit: I've created a sample to show the issue with @auval response.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ProgressBar volumeBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        final VolumeProviderCompat volumeProviderCompat = new VolumeProviderCompat(VolumeProviderCompat.VOLUME_CONTROL_ABSOLUTE, 100, 100) {
            @Override
            public void onAdjustVolume(int direction) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onAdjustVolume " + direction);
                if (direction > 0) {
                    setCurrentVolume(getCurrentVolume() + 5);
                } else if (direction < 0) {
                    setCurrentVolume(getCurrentVolume() - 5);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSetVolumeTo(int volume) {
                super.onSetVolumeTo(volume);
                Log.i(TAG, "onSetVolumeTo " + volume);
            }
        };
        volumeProviderCompat.setCallback(new VolumeProviderCompat.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onVolumeChanged(VolumeProviderCompat volumeProvider) {
                volumeBar.setMax(volumeProvider.getMaxVolume());
                int currentVolume = volumeProvider.getCurrentVolume();
                Log.i(TAG,"onVolumeChanged " + currentVolume);
                volumeBar.setProgress(currentVolume);
            }
        });
        final MediaSessionCompat test = new MediaSessionCompat(this, "Test");
        PlaybackStateCompat.Builder stateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder();
        stateBuilder.setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY | PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE | PlaybackState.ACTION_PAUSE | PlaybackState.ACTION_REWIND | PlaybackState.ACTION_FAST_FORWARD);
        stateBuilder.setState(PlaybackState.STATE_PLAYING, PlaybackState.PLAYBACK_POSITION_UNKNOWN, 1.0f);
        test.setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.build());
        test.setActive(true);
        test.setPlaybackToRemote(volumeProviderCompat);
    }
}
```

This is what happens on the screen:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use [VolumeProviderCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/VolumeProviderCompat.html), because VolumeProvider requires minimum sdk of 21.

1. It's you to decide how many volume steps you want to provide.
2. Divide the max volume by this number, it will give you the value to adjust by on each step.

   - for example, max volume is 100, you decided to provide 5 steps ==> each step will change the volume by 20.
3. Adjust the volume accordingly.

   - for example, current volume is 40, you got volume up event ==> you need to set the volume now to 60.

By the way, nothing in the specifications states that volume control must be linear, you can decide to start with small interval change and increase the jump on each consecutive volume press...

Comment: Are you saying I'm the one that controls the step size? Doesn't the panel that shows up when you press the volume buttons already have a step size it uses?

Comment: Yes, you are in control. There are no pre defined "steps" - you define them by translating the current position to the next position as a result of a volume up event. The UI knows where to place the lever, as a percentage from the value you set and the maximum

Comment: Sorry I guess I'm just not understanding. I think this is what you are telling me to do. Override `onAdjustVolume()`. Then inside there call `setCurrentVolume()` myself with `getCurrentVolume()+-step` but when I do that, while the step works fine, the panel on the phone shows one tiny step first and then a giant step based on my step.

Comment: @casolorz, are you calling `super` inside your overrided method?

Comment: I've done it both ways. If I assume the step is 1 then I call `super`, if I call `setCurrentVolume()` with an arbitrary step then I don't call `super`.

Comment: I added a gif showing what happens and the code. I press the volume down button on the phone a few times and you can see it takes a tiny step and then a large one.

Comment: I don't have a solution for the step+delay+large step. Volume of what do you want to control? If local volume then there is an easier way then VolumeProvider

Comment: Another comment: in onAdjustVolume() you should check boundaries 0..max, not only the direction. ie.                 if (direction > 0 && getCurrentVolume() < max) {
                    setCurrentVolume(getCurrentVolume() + 20);
                } else if (direction < 0 && getCurrentVolume() > 0) {
                    setCurrentVolume(getCurrentVolume() - 20);
                }

Comment: Yeah I figured I had to check boundaries but I don't really want to use my custom step method if the volume panel is not going to look right. And really I don't need custom step sizes, I just need to know what the default step size size is as I'm guessing it could change on different roms.

Comment: Volume of what do you want to control? If local volume then there is an easier way then VolumeProvider

Comment: Ya, same issue here, the UI seems to be set to a step size of 1. It would be nice if we could change that but I can't see how. This is way more complicated than it needs to be.